# How do I add Subsurface Scattering in Blender to a sculpt made and textured in 3DCoat?

Tags: node-editor, subsurface-scattering

I've imported my model with textures/materials from 3DCoat, and I wanted to add some SSS.
I'd like to recreate the effect similar to this one, where it's very intense:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_zV-yTdVDg

I can't figure out which node the artist used and how he mixed it in with the ones imported from 3DCoat. The node setup is only partially visible in the video.

[image]
[image]

Comment: PrincipledBSDF node has emission input, you don't need to add an emission shader separately.